# Is Issuer both required and ignored when querying users by Identity?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/objectidentity?view=graph-rest-1.0) says

> Note: When filtering on the identities property, you must supply both issuer and issuerAssignedId.

However this query:

```
string email = "me@mydomain.com";

IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await client.Users.Request()
            .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Mail, x.OtherMails, x.Identities })
            .Filter($"identities/any(ids:ids/issuerassignedid eq '{email}' and ids/issuer eq 'x')")
            .GetAsync();
```

Returns a single user record:

```
issuerAssignedId: me@mydomain.com
issuer: mydomain.onmicrosoft.com
```

Question:  Why is ids/issuer both required and ignored?

Comment: can you please confirm what do you mean by ignored and also provide more details on what you are looking for

Comment: Ignorted referes to the fact that the filter clause in query is `and ids/issuer eq 'x'` however a row is returned with issuer equal to 'mydomain.onmicrosoft.com'.  Required referrers to the fact that if the issuer clause in the filter is removed the query fails with an error message stating it is required..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this in my setup and I also got the same response from SDK and graph  API. I have filed a Bug for this and kindly refer to this [bug link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/11094)